# How i can get image width after set src attribute without reload page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that if i pass a source of image to it, it should modify the src attribute of $("#image") element, this function is called when i click a button which isn't inside a form (this means that page is not reloaded)

```
function modify_image(image_src){
   $("#image").attr("src", image_src);
}
```

how i can get the width of this image after his **src** changed ?

Comment: does the image change after you click button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Loading an image is async, so you have to wait until it's loaded to get the width :

```
function modify_image(image_src){
   $("#image").on('load', function() {
       var width = this.width;
   })
   .attr("src", image_src)
   .each(function() {
        if (this.complete) $(this).trigger('load');
   });
}
```

**Always** change the source *after* the `onload` event handler has been attached, and for cached images you *must* check the `this.complete` property and trigger the `onload` event yourself.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that the `load` event must be attached directly to the image (as you do here) -- it won't bubble up like other events do, so delegation won't work.

Comment: i try to get also height (var height = this.height();) but it show me TypeError: this.height is not a function
[Break On This Error], what is wrong here ?

Comment: `.height()` is a jQuery method; you need `var height=$(this).height();` or `=this.height;`

Comment: at the least of your code i add console.log(width); but it shows me undefined :(

Comment: @adeneo if i move console.log(width) inside $("#image").on('load',function(){ console.log(width)}); it work fine, i have already declared var width variable outside load function, what is wrong here ?

Comment: @medBo - It's async, so you can't move it out of the load callback

Comment: don't understand 100% what means async but look like i understand 40% :p it works fine now thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

The load event will fire when the image has updated:

```
$("#image").attr("src", image_src)
    .load(function () {
      $(this).width(); // the new image width
    })
```

Comment: [Not always](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877027/jquery-callback-on-image-load-even-when-the-image-is-cached).

Answer (score 0):

You can use load function

```
function modify_image(image_src){
   var img = new Image();
   img.src = image_src;
   img.onload = function () { 
       var width = img.width; 
    };
   $("#image").attr("src", img.src);
}
```

In load function you can fetch its properties such as height

Answer (score 0):

Here's my flavour:

```
    function modify_image(image_src){
       $("#image").attr("src", image_src).load(function () {
            console.log($(this).width());
        });
    }
```