# Can I fire an event after I append() content

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

I am creating a slideshow and would like to know if I can get a Promise out of the append() function so I can trigger an animation only when the next slide is in place.

```
$.when( $('#slides').append('<div class="slide"></div>') ).done(animation);
```

When I try the above, the animation occurs before the slide is appended. My intention is to have the animation only start **after** the slide is appended to the element.

**Update**

My slideshow as dots on the button that, when clicked, trigger (1) the requested slide to be appended to `#slides` and (2) the `left` of the first slide (assuming there are now 2 slides) is decreased, ending with (3) the `:first` slide is removed. Since `append()` is async [@Guffa], the decrementing of the `left` occurs before the `append()` fires.

Example: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MDeSX/1/)

**Update**

I have tried using

```
$.when( $('#slides').append('<div class="slide"></div>').promise() ).then(animation);
```

and it also does not provide the desired animation.

Comment: The `append` method is not asynchronous. The slide is already there when the `append` method returns. What is it that you experience that leads you to think that it is not?

Comment: If you're waiting for an image to load before the slide animates, [there's a few tricks involved](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19122698/901048).